# Java current time method need to increment

Tags: java, date

I have created a method to get the current time, I would like the time to increment 60 seconds or 1 min every time I call this method.  Any help would be appreciated.

// Current method I am using

```
public String currentTime() 
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

// main

```
System.out.println("The time is now: " + d.currentTime());
```

Comment: ...You want to travel to the future using Java?

Comment: To get one minute from now you can use cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to "snap" the current time when the method is first call. The one-second offsets will be added to that in subsequent calls. Then, simply record how many times the method has been called, and apply that as an offset in seconds:

```
static int offset;
static long firstCall;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(currentTime());
    System.out.println(currentTime());
    System.out.println(currentTime());
}

public static String currentTime()
{
    if (offset == 0)
    {
        firstCall = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(firstCall + (offset * 1000 * 60));
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    offset++;
    return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

Just to state the obvious, we have to turn the number of times this has been called (1, 2, 3) to an offset in milliseconds. Thus we multiply by `1000` to get to 1 second, and then `60` to get to minutes.

The first time the method is called, offset is 0. Thus it adds 0 seconds / milliseconds the first time the method is called.

Comment: OP wants the time to increment by 1 minute each call, not be 1 more minute into the future from the time of each call.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks for spotting, code updated to fulfil the requirements properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean: start with current time and add one minute every time the function is called, the solution needs two pieces:

- Remember the current time when it is called for the first time (constructor takes care of that)
- Add one minute from that point on (a class variable is used for that)

  ```
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  import java.util.Calendar;

  public class TestJava {

  public static class GoIntoTheFuture {

      private int minutesToAdd = 0;
      private Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

      public String currentTime() {
         cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE,minutesToAdd++);
         return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
      }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      GoIntoTheFuture g = new GoIntoTheFuture();
      for( int i = 0; i < 5; i ++ )
          System.out.println("The time is now: " + g.currentTime());
  }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.getTime();
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String currentTime() 
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    //add one minute to the current time.
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3, call the [plusMinutes()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusMinutes%28int%29) method.

```java
org.joda.time.DateTime now = new org.joda.time.DateTime();
org.joda.time.DateTime future = now.plusMinutes(1);
```

The accepted answer by jwa uses a static which affects the entire app. Perhaps the original poster wants (not clear). If you want a different incrementing for each of multiple windows or multiple users or multiple threads (such as with servlets), then define a class to track the initial time and track the incrementing. By they way, this increment-a-minute-on-every-call seems like a strange requirement, so perhaps your questions needs to be reworded or explained.

```java
/**
 * Created by Basil Bourque on 2013-11-16.
 * © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
 */
public class FutureClock {

    org.joda.time.DateTime startDateTime = new org.joda.time.DateTime();
    org.joda.time.DateTime incrementedDateTime = startDateTime;

    org.joda.time.DateTime increment() {
        // Increment the previous datetime by one minute. Remember new datetime.
        this.incrementedDateTime = this.incrementedDateTime.plusMinutes(1);
        return this.incrementedDateTime;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FutureClock futureClock = new FutureClock();
        System.out.println( "Incremented minute: " + futureClock.increment() + " while true time is: " + new org.joda.time.DateTime() );
        System.out.println( "Incremented minute: " + futureClock.increment() + " while true time is: " + new org.joda.time.DateTime() );
        System.out.println( "Incremented minute: " + futureClock.increment() + " while true time is: " + new org.joda.time.DateTime() );
        System.out.println( "Incremented minute: " + futureClock.increment() + " while true time is: " + new org.joda.time.DateTime() );

        // Wait over a minute.
        System.out.println( "Please wait a minute…" );
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * 70 );
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        System.out.println( "Next minute: " + futureClock.increment() + " while true time is: " + new org.joda.time.DateTime() );
    }
}
```

When run…

```
Incremented minute: 2013-11-16T22:44:19.571-08:00 while true time is: 2013-11-16T22:43:19.704-08:00
Incremented minute: 2013-11-16T22:45:19.571-08:00 while true time is: 2013-11-16T22:43:19.704-08:00
Incremented minute: 2013-11-16T22:46:19.571-08:00 while true time is: 2013-11-16T22:43:19.704-08:00
Incremented minute: 2013-11-16T22:47:19.571-08:00 while true time is: 2013-11-16T22:43:19.704-08:00
Please wait a minute…
Next minute: 2013-11-16T22:48:19.571-08:00 while true time is: 2013-11-16T22:44:29.705-08:00
```

I omitted some real-world concerns, such as specifying a time zone rather than rely on default, and thread-safety issues if an instance may be called on more than one thread.